# Can I push new promise into array in the middle of Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to figure out how Promise.all works.
My question is: is that ok to push a new promise in the middle of Promise.all() into the same array that was passed earlier? 
For example, I have this code which works just fine: 
https://jsfiddle.net/artheg/z0Lndw1o/14/

```
const promises = [];
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('promise1');
  const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('promise2');
  });
  pushPromise(promise2); // Pushing promise2 to the same array after the promise1 was resolved
});

pushPromise(promise1); // Pushing promise1

function pushPromise(promise) {
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values); // Array [ "promise2", "promise1" ]
});
```

Is this behavior intended or should I always chain promises with .then() instead of pushing a new Promise into the array?

Comment: Your code does not add a Promise to the array "in the middle of Promise.all()".  It builds the array completely and then passes it to Promise.all() after it has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in a promise executor (the function you pass `new Promise`) runs **synchronously**. So `pushPromise(promise2)` has already run before you call `Promise.all`. The array is already filled by the time you call `Promise.all`.

> Can I push new promise into array in the middle of Promise.all()?

Not if you want `Promise.all` to see that promise, no. See [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.all), `Promise.all` loops through the iterable you pass it synchronously, before returning, and before any handlers it (`Promise.all`) sets up on the promises can be called.

Here's an example, note that the promise from `Promise.all` is fulfilled rather than rejecting, even though the code adds a promise to the array that it rejects:

```js
const promises = [
    Promise.resolve(1),
    Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => {
        promises.push(Promise.reject(new Error("failed")));
    }),
    Promise.resolve(3),
];
Promise.all(promises)
.then(results => {
    console.log(`results (${results.length}): ${results.join(", ")}`);
    console.log(`promises.length: ${promises.length}`);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you push the promises to the array *synchronously*. `Promise.all` works with the promises that are in the array by the time you pass it in.

Example of a Promise added asynchronously:

```
 const promises = [Promise.resolve(1)];

 setTimeout(() => promises.push(Promise.resolve(2)), 0);

 Promise.all(promises).then(console.log); // [1]
```